# Regular expression to match with the start and the end of a line

Tags: notepad++, regex

I'm using Notepad++ and I would like to find the regular expression which match with the start and the end of a line. For exemple:
*En este nivel se estudia la forma de construir los dispositivos (electrónicos)*
I want that the regular expression matches with 'E' and ')'.
I have tried ^[E]+)$

Thank you!

Comment: Answer on [so]- [regex - How do I match an entire line in Notepad++ for search/replace? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053068/how-do-i-match-an-entire-line-in-notepad-for-search-replace)

Comment: `^E.+\)$` should work, if the line begins with `E` and ends with `)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a single regular expression that matches the first and the last character of each string, then here it is: `(^.|.$)`.